# Spring AOP Pointcuts

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I am new to Spring AOP triggers. I have the following pointcut triggers in my code. Only the first pointcut trigger (com.src.a()) is working and the remaining below are not triggering when all the four pointcuts are defined. But when I define only one pointcut trigger in any of the four, it is working fine. Not sure why the triggers after 1st trigger is not working when all four are defined. Requesting help...

```
         @AfterReturning ( 
      pointcut = "execution(* com.src.a(..)) "
     + "OR execution(* com.src.b(..)) "
     + "OR execution(* com.src.c(..)) " 
     + "OR execution(* com.src.d(..))")

    public void src ( ) throws Throwable {

    ....
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define multiple pointcuts by define "dumy" pointcuts and combine them. Maybe the `&&` will also work in your aproach( replace 'OR' with &&)

From the docs 
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/aop.html

```
    @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
    private void anyPublicOperation() {}

    @Pointcut("within(com.xyz.someapp.trading..*")
    private void inTrading() {}

    @Pointcut("anyPublicOperation() && inTrading()")
    private void tradingOperation() {}
```

Comment: Replacing OR with && will break... As && means AND and not OR... Which would render his pointcut useless as it will never match all the parts at once!... Instead of && try || (which means OR). Also defining them directly or by named pointcuts doesn't matter, the runtime result will be the same.